# Filter a List with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Can any one help me with this function that filter elements

```
Public Sub adjectAllNormals()

    Dim qry As LinkedList(Of CElement) = From elm In Elements
              From id In SelectIDs()
              Where elm.ID = id

    Console.WriteLine(qry.Count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A Linq query returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, not a `LinkedList(Of T)`... You can try that instead:

```
Public Sub adjectAllNormals()

    Dim qry As IEnumerable(Of CElement) = From elm In Elements
              From id In SelectIDs()
              Where elm.ID = id
              Select elm

    Dim list As New LinkedList(Of CElement)(qry)
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count)
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't compile,  you should add `Select elm`

Comment: True, but now you are (implicitly) selecting an anonymous object with fields elm and id (there is a double From clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ids = SelectIDs().ToList()
Dim qry = From elm In Elements Where ids.Contains(elm.ID) select elm
```